# Websphere liberty: asynchronous scheduling processes

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am migrating my application from websphere traditional to liberty.

The code makes use of asynchronous scheduling processes.

How do I migrate this code to websphere liberty.

When trying to configure this in liberty (server.xml) I found 3 elements

a) Managed Scheduled Executor

b) Persistent Scheduled Executor

c) Managed Executor

Which of this can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Options (A) and (C) can be used by enabling the `concurrent-1.0` feature in server.xml.

Usually these do not need to be explicitly configured in server.xml, and can be directly used in your application like so:

```java
import javax.enterprise.concurrent.*;
// ...

@Resource
ManagedScheduledExecutorService scheduledExec;

@Resource
ManagedExecutorService exec;
```

The "scheduled" executor service extends the non-scheduled variant, and adds some methods for invoking tasks on some sort of schedule, such as a fixed rate or a fixed delay.

The javadoc for `ManagedExecutorService` can be found here: https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/javaee/8/#package=javax/enterprise/concurrent/package-frame.html&class=javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedScheduledExecutorService.html

For option (B), this is an SPI component that allows EJB timers to be persisted. Applications do not use it directly, but whenever an EJB uses [`@Schedule(persistent=true, ...)`](https://openliberty.io/docs/ref/javaee/8/#package=javax/enterprise/concurrent/package-frame.html&class=javax/ejb/Schedule.html) then the persistent timer service will be used.